# Installshield LE TFS Build succeeds but does not produce output

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, installshield, installshield-le

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 which contains multiple projects - a web application, some class libraries, a couple of database projects and an Installshield LE 2013 project.

If I build the solution for Release, locally, the ISLE project creates and outputs a setup.exe and associated msi etc.  However, if I build the solution with Release configuration through TFS 2013 build automation, the build succeeds, produces outputs for all projects and drops them in the drop location with the exception of the ISLE project.  No setup.exe and no .msi files are created on the build machine.  The tail end of the build log is included below on **Detailed** mode:

*I modified my islproj file to include an AfterGet target as suggested by [This Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/436663a2-850a-467a-ab1a-d78c77695087/build-fails-with-installshield-project-2200-could-not-overwrite-file?forum=tfsbuild) to avoid the -2200 error described there, and you can see this target in the log in case you are wondering why it's there...*

How can I ask the build agent to actually compile my installer?

```
....omitted other projects build logging....

Task "MSBuild"
     Global Properties:
       Configuration=SingleImage
       Platform=
       BuildingSolutionFile=true
       CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents=<SolutionConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{0D638421-Bxx3-43BC-A6F1-8992DB9770C8}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.csproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Release|x86</ProjectConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{A31FE3AA-Fxx6-4AAB-B934-750C0F1C6013}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Reports\PROJECTNAMEReportsLibrary.csproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Release|x86</ProjectConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{D8CD6EA6-5xx2-44E2-B3C1-954E1DF99303}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Database\PROJECTNAME.Database.sqlproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Release|x86</ProjectConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{BA6453AD-DxxB-466C-9579-BF631B75C2E8}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAMEImport.Database\PROJECTNAMEImport.Database.sqlproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Release|x86</ProjectConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{951766F3-1xx0-40A4-80D7-1FEDDD922A4E}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Tests\PROJECTNAME.Tests.csproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Release|x86</ProjectConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{45370F77-9xx5-4689-8236-B6DBECE591D9}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">SingleImage<ProjectDependency Project="{0D638421-Bxx3-43BC-A6F1-8992DB9770C8}" /><ProjectDependency Project="{147B816F-2xxA-4FA9-873E-47615DCFAFFA}" /><ProjectDependency Project="{A31FE3AA-FAF6-4AAB-Bxx4-750C0F1C6013}" /></ProjectConfiguration>
       <ProjectConfiguration Project="{147B816F-2xxA-4FA9-873E-47615DCFAFFA}" AbsolutePath="C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Files\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Files.csproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Release|x86</ProjectConfiguration>
     </SolutionConfiguration>
       SolutionDir=C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\
       SolutionExt=.sln
       SolutionFileName=PROJECTNAME.sln
       SolutionName=PROJECTNAME
       SolutionPath=C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.sln
 9>Project "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj.metaproj" (9) is building "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj" (10) on node 1 (default targets).
10>Building with tools version "3.5".
10>Target "AfterGet" in project "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj" (entry point):
   Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
   Task "Exec"
     Command:
     attrib -r "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isl"
   Done executing task "Exec".
10>Done building target "AfterGet" in project "PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj".
10>Done Building Project "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj" (default targets).
 9>Done executing task "MSBuild".
 9>Done building target "Build" in project "PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj.metaproj".
 9>Done Building Project "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full\PROJECTNAME.Setup.Full.isproj.metaproj" (default targets).
 1>Done executing task "MSBuild".
 1>Done building target "Build" in project "PROJECTNAME.sln".
 1>Done Building Project "C:\Builds\1\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME Release Build\src\PROJECTNAME\Trunk\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.sln" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:02:02.06
```

Comment: I am fighting this myself.  I have VS2013 and TFS2013.  I have been reading through so many sites with no luck.  The TfvcTemplate.12.xaml file does not work.  I had to resort to the default to get rid of many of the errors.  My TFS Build succeeds but it ends with

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets: -1527: No files are included in the project.

Comment: I can build the correct MSI file on the development PC AND can build the file on the TFS Build Server using the same code and VS 2013. However, when using a Build Definition hit by VS 2013 on the development PC, ISLE 2013 says there are no files in the project when there ARE files defined.